# How to store the user's last visited page in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails.

I have a typical problem that is , say i have a category model.For example an user goes to categories/1 page(here categories is the category resource and 1 is id number).

Now i need to store that particular category page.
So that when the user log in again i can redirect the user to that particular category page.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to persist that category id across sessions, so you probably have to stick it in the database. Create a `category_id` attribute on your user to save the category id. Then, when the user next logs in you can send them to their last visited category.

Here's some quick sample code:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    current_user.category = @category
    current_user.save
  end
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def login
    ... auth logic ...
    if current_user.category_id.present?
      redirect_to current_user.category
    end
  end
end
```

And your user model:

```
class User < AR
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way this is achieved by adding a field to the User model where you store a relation to the other model, `category_id` for instance, and update this when they view any particular category.

Then on login you can redirect to this record, if any is defined.